# What's the difference between an Aggregate and a Model

Tags: domain-driven-design

We've recently taken up DDD approach to design. Some of our developers are using the Aggregate pattern (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) but to me this sounds very similar to the well-known Model approach (from MVC).

> Aggregate is a pattern in Domain-Driven Design. A DDD aggregate is a
> cluster of domain objects that can be treated as a single unit. An
> example may be an order and its line-items, these will be separate
> objects, but it's useful to treat the order (together with its line
> items) as a single aggregate.

Is it just the DDD terminology for the same thing or is there a place for both aggregates and models in DDD?

Comment: An aggregate is an element of the domain "model". So, to some degree, your aggregates, value objects, entities, etc, are part of that model. MVC's strictly speaking.

Comment: in MVC your model consists of many classes though. e.g. my.app.model.ClassX - so this just seems like conceptually the same thing as an Aggregate. A bunch of related application data.

Comment: An aggregate is not a bunch of classes. Is rather a boundary that gives consistency to a bunch of classes

Comment: I mean your link sums it up. Makes me wonder what you are doing with your models

Comment: @Ewan and that definition could be applied to a Model too - a conceptual grouping of data that defines a specific piece of the domain.

Comment: @Mr.Boy You can think of a Model having multiple aggregates. It will facilitate thinking about those things.

Comment: @Mr.Boy if the way you create your model classes for a particular MVC tripple is by encapsulating a number of collaborating objects behind one object that provides an interface to, and defines high-level behaviors of, the entire group, and acts as a consistency boundary, then you could say it's the same. But, generally speaking, in MVC, the model part is not particularly well-elaborated, it's just a somewhat generic term for some part of the domain model. It doesn't tell you how to structure it.

Answer (score 5):

> What's the difference between an Aggregate and a Model

## MVC

> The model of an application is the domain-specific software simulation or implementation of the application's central structure. [Krasner/Pope 1988](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eredmiles/ics227-SQ04/papers/KrasnerPope88.pdf)

> Models are those components of the system application that actually do the work (simulation of the application domain).  They are kept quite distinct from *views*, which display aspects of the models.  Controllers are used to send messages to the model, and provide the interface between the model with its associated views and the interactive user interface devices (eg., keyboard, mouse). [Krasner/Pope 1988](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eredmiles/ics227-SQ04/papers/KrasnerPope88.pdf)

## Domain Driven Design

Aggregates, on the other hand, are a lifecycle management pattern that appears in the implementation of the domain model - in other words, within the model layer.

> ...we need an abstraction for encapsulating references within the model.  An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.

To my mind, the model in MVC and the model layer in DDD are close analogs of one another - they are the computer's representation of the user's/actor's mental model.

Aggregates, on the other hand, are a pattern for organizing objects within the model layer.

Answer (score 2):

An essential feature of an Aggregate in DDD is that it is a consistency boundary, meaning that any checks for what it is and isn't allowed to be or do can deal with the entire aggregate, and it should be loaded into memory and saved to permanent storage as a whole - generally using a database transaction if it's stored in a database.

Between separate aggregates DDD says there shouldn't be such tight rules, or if they exist we should accept that the application may break them on occasion, such as if two operations are happening at the same time, because we don't want to be forced to load and save everything at once to check for consistency. We can fix any inconsistencies if necessary after they happen instead of completely preventing them.

The term Model is somewhat vague, but I haven't seen anyone say that a "Model" is a consistency boundary in the same way.